# Changing text to link with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My goal is to change text in span .name into  element with link-

```
  <div class="input-wrap">
      <span class="name">favorite 1</span>
  </div>
```

How can I use JS to add link to this element so as it looks like that:

```
 <div class="input-wrap">
      <span class="name"><a href="/specyficwebsite.html">favourite 1</a></span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

`.wrapInner()` wraps element around passed value.

Try this:

```
$(".name").wrapInner("<a href='/specyficwebsite.html'></a>");
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/7m7Cg/)

Answer (score 2):

You could:

```
$('span.name').html(function () {
    return $('<a>').attr('href', '/specyficwebsite.html').text($(this).text());
});
```

See [demo jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/BEbR2/1/).

Generated HTML:

```
<span class="name"><a href="/specyficwebsite.html">favourite 1</a></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `.wrapInner()` like

```
$(".name").wrapInner( '<a href="/specyficwebsite.html"></a>' );
```

See this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hY2MK/1/) You can also try like

```
var txt = $('.name').text();
$('.name').html('<a href="/specyficwebsite.html">' + txt + '</a>');
```

Or directly

```
$('.name').html('<a href="/specyficwebsite.html">' + $('.name').text() + '</a>');
```

Try this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hY2MK/)

Comment: Can tell me the reason to down it..??

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way:

```
$(".name").html(function(){
$(this).wrap("<a href='/specyficwebsite.html'></a>")
})
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wASgw/)

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
        $(function(){
            var link = '<a href="/specyficwebsite.html">'+$('.name').text()+'</a>';
            $('.name').html(link);
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rBL3D/1/)**

```
var $name = $(".name");
var txt = $name.text();
$name.html('<a href="/specyficwebsite.html">' + txt + '</a>');
```